# using Fiddler to get data is ok, but direct connect with browser **404 Not Found**

Tags: fiddler

when I using fiddler 4 can capture the following link:

http://xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx/xxxx/xxxx.js?r=0071563856136000

RAW

```
GET http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx.js?r=0071563856136000 HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxxx.xxx
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://xxx.xxxx.xxxx/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: zh-TW,zh;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: UM_distinctid=16c1d091d0422d-04557b6712904a-c343162-1fa400-16c1d091d05561; win007BfCookie=null; bfWin007FirstMatchTime=2019,6,23,08,00,00
```

Data

```
sData[1656981]=[[0.80,0.75,1.02,0.80,0.75,1.11,,,],[1.62,3.55,4.55,1.62,3.70,5.10,,,],[0.99,2.5,0.81,0.90,2.5,0.96,,,],[0.81,0.25,1.01,0.82,0.25,1.06,,,],[0.95,1.00,0.85,0.91,1,0.95,,,],[2.21,2.13,5.00,2.26,2.15,5.20,,,]];sData[1667054]=[[0.85,1.25,0.97,0.82,1,1.02,0.70,0,1.16],[1.30,4.35,8.20,1.45,4.00,6.20,1.01,13.50,16.50],[0.85,2.25,0.95,0.90,2.5,0.92,4.76,2.5,0.03],[0.90,0.25,0.94,0.70,0.25,1.16,0.50,0,1.51],[0.89,1.00,0.93,0.95,1,0.87,3.84,0.5,0.08],[2.21,2.15,4.95,2.08,2.14,5.70,11.00,1.03,16.00]];
```

but when i direct click the link, **404 Not Found**

http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.js?r=0071563856136000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service wants the "referer" header set.

```
curl -vvv 'http://xxx.xxxxx.com/xxxx/xxxx.js?r=0071563856136000' -H 'Referer: http://xxxx.xxx.xxx'
```

This is a common, but useless, security mechanism.